Does Swift have an equivalent to C#'s `#region`?
I'm looking for an equivalent way to create labeled code folding regions in Swift.
In C# you can do this with the #region directive, which is a no-op that just creates a code folding section that you can use to organize code within long functions.
Does Swift have this?

Xcode provides code folding. It's not a feature of the specific language. It works with at least Swift and Objective-C.

Don't think this is supported in Xcode, but in AppCode you can use //region and //endregion.

Frankly, if you have "long functions", you should be breaking them down into smaller functions. Then you can just fold the smaller functions.

@Sweeper I ended up doing this, but I decided to leave the question up anyway in case there's an answer.

@HangarRash Yes, Xcode implements code folding. When using C# in VS/VSC, the IDE creates a new code folding section on #region directives. I was asking if there is a similar way to force XC to create a code folding section in Swift, beyond the ones it already creates for functions & closures.

@laptou Xcode lets you create a folding region for any pair of curly braces. In Objective-C you can create an arbitrary folding region by adding a pair of curly braces where you need the region. But Swift doesn't support sticking code in an extra pair of curly braces. So the answer to your question is "no".
